How to ensure energy conservation of a coat layer on top of an arbitrary BSDF?
Recent approximate techniques for energy conservation of conductors / dielectrics rely on the precomputation of the directional albedo for the conductor / dielectric BSDF. [Conty & Kulla 2017], [Turquin 2019]
This approach of precomputing the directional albedo isn't feasible for an arbitrary coated BSDF because we don't know in advance what the BSDF below the coat layer is going to be.
What would be a good solution? Is on-the-fly Monte Carlo integration of the directional albedo (which would require sampling and evaluating the coat layer and everything that's below so that's expensive) the only proper solution and there is no faster in-between?
